# Циклическое авто фотографирование

Tags: java, android-studio

Никак не получается сделать автофотографирование с заданным числом фото. Если использовать для фото метод onClick и нажимать несколько раз - всё в порядке, но ставя код в цикл for, даже используя handler, - вылетает ошибка, а в папке пусто. Один из многих опробованных вариантов:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {   

 for (int i=0; i<5; i=i+1){ 
.... тут кусок задаёт имя и положение нового фото ....
camera.takePicture(null, null, null, MainActivity.this);
SystemClock.sleep(5000); // паузы для фото на всякий пожарный.
}
  }
        }, 5000);
```

PS Код выше сильно упрощён, естественно есть onPictureTaken и др, просто как место самой проблемы, реальный код сложнее с использованием нового имени для каждого фото в отдельных классах ... Я явно чего то не знаю, а вот чего - не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать не `SystemClock.sleep(5000)`, а сделать вот так:

```
for (int i=1; i<6; i++){ 
    new Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                camera.takePicture(null, null, null, MainActivity.this);
            }
    }, i*5000);
}
```

Или так:

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 5) {
       @Override
       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onFinish() {

       }
}.start();
```

А вообще пауза вроде делается вот так:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch(Exeption ignored){}
```

Comment: Всё прекрасно заработало с new CountDownTimer, даже поудалял лишние переменные.